# Performance impact of using reflection instead of an "Options" class

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to refactor a service by providing some options on what to bring back. I can't decide what is best way to go between the below

**A. Use a class for the options**
Create a new class for the options like

```
    public class Options
    {
        public bool Addresses { get; set; }
        public bool Documents { get; set; }
    }
```

and call the services as below

```
    public List<Entity> GetEntitiesByOptions(List<int> entityIds, Options options)
    {
        if (options.Addresses)
        {
            // Add the addresses
        }

        if (options.Documents)
        {
            // Add the Documents
        }
    }
```

**or B. Use the type of class as a parameter**

and use with something like that

```
    public List<Entity> GetEntitiesByOptions(List<int> entityIds, List<Type> options)
    {
        if (options.Any(x => x == typeof(Address)))
        {
            // Add the addresses
        }

        if (options.Any(x => x == typeof(Document)))
        {
            // Add the Documents
        }
    }
```

Would there be a big impact in the performance if I use reflection?

Comment: Have you considered to use [OneOf](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf) or [Either](https://louthy.github.io/language-ext/LanguageExt.Core/LanguageExt/Either_L_R.htm) constructs?

Comment: @PeterCsala thanks for the suggestion. I will take a look at them.

Comment: Looks like a regular question for StackOverflow, not Code Review. You may test the performance easily with `Stopwatch` and accurately with `Benchmark.NET`.